# Scala Maven project in intelliji not auto compiling on save

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, scala-maven-plugin

I have a scala maven project inside an already available multi module java project in intellij(2012.1.2), intellij not auto compiling the scala project on save. I am not facing this issue for java modules in the same project. I could only run the modified scala code after manual maven compile.

I am using scala-maven-plugin version 3.3.2 and enabled "Build Project Automatically" but this doesnt make any changes.

Kindly help to resolve this problem.

Comment: What is your pom.xml (at least the section about scala) ? What is  the command you use to build via maven cli ? Why not use a more recent version of the scala-maven-plugin ?

Comment: Share the sample project where it can be reproduced. Most probably, its a project-level configuration problem. Try "Save actions" plugin: https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions

Comment: Thank you for the response, issue got resolved after i update to latest intellij IDE.